# I have a problem with decimals adding weirdly

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

My code is working well until I get to the program with my output now falling in acceptable perimeters.

I am adding like this:

```
using System;

namespace ITSS131
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello what is your car loan amount.");
            decimal loan = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("What is your APR");
            decimal APR = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    

            Console.WriteLine("What is the monthly payment");
            int monthlypayment = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                       

            int currentmonth = 0;

            int u = 0;

            int c = 1; 
            while (loan >= 0.00m)
            {
                decimal.Round(APR);
                decimal TAX = APR / 12.00m / 100.00m;
                decimal.Round(TAX);
                decimal TAX2 = TAX * loan;                
                decimal Tax3 = monthlypayment - TAX2;

                decimal.Round(loan = loan + TAX2 - monthlypayment);
                currentmonth++;

                Console.WriteLine($"Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance");
                Console.WriteLine($"{currentmonth} {TAX2.ToString("C")} {Tax3.ToString("C")} {loan.ToString("C")}");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is suppose to be

```
    1     $78.75     $271.25   $20,728.75
    2     $77.73     $272.27   $20,456.48
    3     $76.71     $273.29   $20,183.19
    4     $75.69     $274.31   $19,908.88
    5     $74.66     $275.34   $19,633.54
    6     $73.63     $276.37   $19,357.17
    7     $72.59     $277.41   $19,079.76
    8     $71.55     $278.45   $18,801.31
    9     $70.50     $279.50   $18,521.81
   10     $69.46     $280.54   $18,241.27
   11     $68.40     $281.60   $17,959.67
   12     $67.35     $282.65   $17,677.02
   13     $66.29     $283.71   $17,393.31
   14     $65.22     $284.78   $17,108.53
   15     $64.16     $285.84   $16,822.69
   16     $63.09     $286.91   $16,535.78
   17     $62.01     $287.99   $16,247.79
   18     $60.93     $289.07   $15,958.72
   19     $59.85     $290.15   $15,668.57
   20     $58.76     $291.24   $15,377.33
   21     $57.66     $292.34   $15,084.99
   22     $56.57     $293.43   $14,791.56
   23     $55.47     $294.53   $14,497.03
   24     $54.36     $295.64   $14,201.39
   25     $53.26     $296.74   $13,904.65
   26     $52.14     $297.86   $13,606.79
   27     $51.03     $298.97   $13,307.82
   28     $49.90     $300.10   $13,007.72
   29     $48.78     $301.22   $12,706.50
   30     $47.65     $302.35   $12,404.15
   31     $46.52     $303.48   $12,100.67
   32     $45.38     $304.62   $11,796.05
   33     $44.24     $305.76   $11,490.29
   34     $43.09     $306.91   $11,183.38
   35     $41.94     $308.06   $10,875.32
   36     $40.78     $309.22   $10,566.10
   37     $39.62     $310.38   $10,255.72
   38     $38.46     $311.54    $9,944.18
   39     $37.29     $312.71    $9,631.47
   40     $36.12     $313.88    $9,317.59
   41     $34.94     $315.06    $9,002.53
   42     $33.76     $316.24    $8,686.29
   43     $32.57     $317.43    $8,368.86
   44     $31.38     $318.62    $8,050.24
   45     $30.19     $319.81    $7,730.43
   46     $28.99     $321.01    $7,409.42
   47     $27.79     $322.21    $7,087.21
   48     $26.58     $323.42    $6,763.79
   49     $25.36     $324.64    $6,439.15
   50     $24.15     $325.85    $6,113.30
   51     $22.92     $327.08    $5,786.22
   52     $21.70     $328.30    $5,457.92
   53     $20.47     $329.53    $5,128.39
   54     $19.23     $330.77    $4,797.62
   55     $17.99     $332.01    $4,465.61
   56     $16.75     $333.25    $4,132.36
   57     $15.50     $334.50    $3,797.86
   58     $14.24     $335.76    $3,462.10
   59     $12.98     $337.02    $3,125.08
   60     $11.72     $338.28    $2,786.80
   61     $10.45     $339.55    $2,447.25
   62      $9.18     $340.82    $2,106.43
   63      $7.90     $342.10    $1,764.33
   64      $6.62     $343.38    $1,420.95
   65      $5.33     $344.67    $1,076.28
   66      $4.04     $345.96      $730.32
   67      $2.74     $347.26      $383.06
   68      $1.44     $348.56       $34.50
   68      $0.13      $34.50        $0.00
```

but instead i get

```
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
1      $78.75      $271.25     $20,728.75
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
2      $77.73      $272.27     $20,456.48
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
3      $76.71      $273.29     $20,183.19
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
4      $75.69      $274.31     $19,908.88
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
5      $74.66      $275.34     $19,633.54
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
6      $73.63      $276.37     $19,357.17
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
7      $72.59      $277.41     $19,079.76
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
8      $71.55      $278.45     $18,801.30
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
9      $70.50      $279.50     $18,521.81
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
10      $69.46      $280.54     $18,241.27
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
11      $68.40      $281.60     $17,959.67
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
12      $67.35      $282.65     $17,677.02
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
13      $66.29      $283.71     $17,393.31
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
14      $65.22      $284.78     $17,108.53
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
15      $64.16      $285.84     $16,822.69
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
16      $63.09      $286.91     $16,535.78
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
17      $62.01      $287.99     $16,247.78
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
18      $60.93      $289.07     $15,958.71
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
19      $59.85      $290.15     $15,668.56
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
20      $58.76      $291.24     $15,377.32
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
21      $57.66      $292.34     $15,084.98
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
22      $56.57      $293.43     $14,791.55
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
23      $55.47      $294.53     $14,497.02
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
24      $54.36      $295.64     $14,201.38
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
25      $53.26      $296.74     $13,904.64
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
26      $52.14      $297.86     $13,606.78
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
27      $51.03      $298.97     $13,307.80
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
28      $49.90      $300.10     $13,007.71
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
29      $48.78      $301.22     $12,706.49
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
30      $47.65      $302.35     $12,404.14
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
31      $46.52      $303.48     $12,100.65
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
32      $45.38      $304.62     $11,796.03
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
33      $44.24      $305.76     $11,490.27
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
34      $43.09      $306.91     $11,183.35
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
35      $41.94      $308.06     $10,875.29
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
36      $40.78      $309.22     $10,566.07
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
37      $39.62      $310.38     $10,255.70
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
38      $38.46      $311.54     $9,944.16
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
39      $37.29      $312.71     $9,631.45
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
40      $36.12      $313.88     $9,317.56
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
41      $34.94      $315.06     $9,002.50
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
42      $33.76      $316.24     $8,686.26
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
43      $32.57      $317.43     $8,368.84
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
44      $31.38      $318.62     $8,050.22
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
45      $30.19      $319.81     $7,730.41
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
46      $28.99      $321.01     $7,409.40
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
47      $27.79      $322.21     $7,087.18
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
48      $26.58      $323.42     $6,763.76
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
49      $25.36      $324.64     $6,439.12
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
50      $24.15      $325.85     $6,113.27
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
51      $22.92      $327.08     $5,786.20
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
52      $21.70      $328.30     $5,457.89
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
53      $20.47      $329.53     $5,128.36
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
54      $19.23      $330.77     $4,797.59
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
55      $17.99      $332.01     $4,465.58
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
56      $16.75      $333.25     $4,132.33
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
57      $15.50      $334.50     $3,797.83
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
58      $14.24      $335.76     $3,462.07
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
59      $12.98      $337.02     $3,125.05
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
60      $11.72      $338.28     $2,786.77
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
61      $10.45      $339.55     $2,447.22
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
62      $9.18      $340.82     $2,106.40
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
63      $7.90      $342.10     $1,764.30
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
64      $6.62      $343.38     $1,420.91
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
65      $5.33      $344.67     $1,076.24
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
66      $4.04      $345.96     $730.28
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
67      $2.74      $347.26     $383.01
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
68      $1.44      $348.56     $34.45
Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance
69      $0.13      $349.87     ($315.42)
```

Can anyone help me get to 0?

Comment: $0.00 is what i need to get but i am only getting ($315.42)

Comment: Think about where `Console.WriteLine($"Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance");` is located, and compare that to your output - it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Emm, remove the `Console.WriteLine($"Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance");`?

Comment: One thing to also note is that you're doing nothing with the rounded values: `decimal.Round(APR);` should be `APR = decimal.Round(APR);`

Comment: I'm guessing `decimal.Round(loan = loan + TAX2 - monthlypayment);` is supposed to be written as `loan = decimal.Round(loan + TAX2 - monthlypayment);`

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance");

       while (loan > 0.10m)
        {
            decimal TAX = APR / 12.00m / 100.00m;
            decimal TAX2 = decimal.Round(TAX * loan, 2);
            decimal Tax3 = decimal.Round(monthlypayment - TAX2, 2);
            if (loan > monthlypayment-TAX2) loan = loan + TAX2 - monthlypayment;
            else
            {
                Tax3 = loan + TAX2;
                loan = 0m;
            }
             currentmonth++;

                Console.WriteLine($"{currentmonth} {TAX2.ToString("C")} {Tax3.ToString("C")} {loan.ToString("C")}");
             }
```

Comment: i still cant get a balance out put of $0.00. Is there something else i am missing

Comment: Pls tell me loan, apr, and motnlypayment values and I will help you.

Comment: You've changed the incorrect code `decimal.Round(APR);` to another incorrect code `decimal.Round(APR,2);`. Can you please show the OP how it should be done?

Comment: loan 21000     apr 4.5     monthly 350

Answer (score 0):

Note that your last payment is not a full payment amount - with an arbitrary APR and payment amount you will not always get a full, even amortization schedule. If you want to just show the smaller payment at the end just change

```
decimal Tax3 = monthlypayment - TAX2;
loan = loan + TAX2 - monthlypayment;
decimal.Round(loan,2);
```

to

```
decimal Tax3 = Math.Max(monthlypayment - TAX2, loan) ;
loan = loan - Tax3;
loan = decimal.Round(loan,2);
```

That will fix three things:

1. cap the principal at the remaining principal balance
2. re-use the principal amount value in the decrease of balance formula
3. capture the result of `round` (round does not change the original value - it *returns* the rounded value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Program
{
    private static Ink InkOverlay { get; set; }
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello what is your car loan amount.");
        decimal loan = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("What is your APR");
        decimal APR = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("What is the monthly payment");
        decimal monthlypayment = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int currentmonth = 0;

        int u = 0;

        int c = 1;
        while (loan > 0.00m)
        {
            decimal.Round(APR);
            decimal TAX = APR / 12.00m / 100.00m;
            decimal.Round(TAX);
            decimal TAX2 = TAX * loan;

            if((loan + TAX2) < monthlypayment)
            {
                monthlypayment = loan + TAX2;
            }

            decimal Tax3 = monthlypayment - TAX2;

            decimal.Round(loan = loan + TAX2 - monthlypayment);
            currentmonth++;

            Console.WriteLine($"Month - Interst - Principle -   Balance");
            Console.WriteLine($"{currentmonth} {TAX2.ToString("C")} {Tax3.ToString("C")} {loan.ToString("C")}");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of a rewrite of your code to show how this might best be structured.

I have specifically renamed variables to make their meaning clear.

Here is the code.

```
    Console.WriteLine("hello what is your car loan amount.");
    decimal loanPrincipal = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), 2);
```

Let's round this immediately. Since we're using `decimal` any calculations involving addition and subtraction of rounded values are guaranteed to have a rounded result.

```
    Console.WriteLine("What is your APR");
    decimal apr = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) / 100m;
    decimal mpr = (decimal)(System.Math.Pow(1.0 + (double)apr, 1.0 / 12.0) - 1.0);
```

Let's parse the `apr` and immediately divide by `100m` to get the value that the percentage represents.

And also let's compute the correct monthly rate. Just remember that if you apply the monthly interest rate 12 times then the resulting increase should be annual rate. It's a compounding calculation, not a simple one. Should you have been instructed to use simple interest then you can change this formula to `decimal mpr = apr / 12m;`.

```
    Console.WriteLine("What is the monthly payment");
    decimal monthlyPayment = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), 2);
```

Like the principal, let's parse and round at the same time.

Now the loop looks like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine($"Month - Principal - Interest - Payment - Balance");
    for (int currentMonth = 1; ; currentMonth++)
    {
        decimal monthlyInterest = Math.Ceiling(100m * loanPrincipal * mpr) / 100m;
        monthlyPayment = Math.Min(monthlyPayment, loanPrincipal + monthlyInterest);
        decimal updatedPrincipal = loanPrincipal + monthlyInterest - monthlyPayment;

        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
            currentMonth,
            loanPrincipal.ToString("C"),
            monthlyInterest.ToString("C"),
            monthlyPayment.ToString("C"),
            updatedPrincipal.ToString("C"));

        loanPrincipal = updatedPrincipal;

        if (loanPrincipal == 0m)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

The key part here is that I computed the interest, monthly payment, and the updated principal in the three lines at the start of the loop.

The interest is computed using `Math.Ceiling` and not `Math.Round` as banks like to always get a whole cent regardless of the fraction. In other words, they don't like rounding down.

The monthly payment is either the current monthly payment or the amount required to pay off the loan.

And I compute the updated principal to make formatting the data easy.

I then display the data.

Finally, I set the principal to the updated principal amount and then break out of the loop if the loan is paid off.

```
Month - Principal - Interest - Payment - Balance
1 $5,000.00 $39.88 $500.00 $4,539.88
2 $4,539.88 $36.21 $500.00 $4,076.09
3 $4,076.09 $32.51 $500.00 $3,608.60
4 $3,608.60 $28.78 $500.00 $3,137.38
5 $3,137.38 $25.02 $500.00 $2,662.40
6 $2,662.40 $21.24 $500.00 $2,183.64
7 $2,183.64 $17.42 $500.00 $1,701.06
8 $1,701.06 $13.57 $500.00 $1,214.63
9 $1,214.63 $9.69 $500.00 $724.32
10 $724.32 $5.78 $500.00 $230.10
11 $230.10 $1.84 $231.94 $0.00
```